# Recover commit lost during commit amend

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-amend

I've made a mistake I guess

Yesterday I created a new branch (`feature/crud-suppliers`), then yesterday and today I worked on that branch.
30 minutes ago, after I finished my changes I added the files modified and did a `git commit --amend --no-edit` then I remembered that I didn't commit anything before, so I wanted to add a message to the commit.

I thought that with `git rebase -i HEAD~2` I could go inside and change the message, but the commit wasn't there, so i just pressed to exit `ctrl`+`X` and noticed that it completed the rebase..

After that my edits disapear, few minutes ago I pushed everything to check if i could find the edits on github but no luck.

I tried `git reflog` but checking the hash before the rebase didn't show my edits.

this is my git reflog:

```
637b687 (HEAD, master) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from feature/crud-suppliers to 637b687
a55e9d9 (origin/feature/crud-suppliers, feature/crud-suppliers) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from 3f5931ac661a4d4ee983fe0a173ae309a874be83 to feature/crud-suppliers
3f5931a HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from 8dd9857224adf665df1d5d981c067d6068c3bea6 to 3f5931a
8dd9857 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from feature/crud-suppliers to 8dd9857
a55e9d9 (origin/feature/crud-suppliers, feature/crud-suppliers) HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from feature/crud-products to feature/crud-suppliers
9ed4250 (origin/feature/crud-products, feature/crud-products) HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from develop to feature/crud-products
069daa3 (origin/develop, develop) HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from feature/crud-suppliers to develop
a55e9d9 (origin/feature/crud-suppliers, feature/crud-suppliers) HEAD@{7}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/feature/crud-suppliers
a55e9d9 (origin/feature/crud-suppliers, feature/crud-suppliers) HEAD@{8}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~2
a55e9d9 (origin/feature/crud-suppliers, feature/crud-suppliers) HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from 3f5931ac661a4d4ee983fe0a173ae309a874be83 to feature/crud-suppliers
3f5931a HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from a55e9d98dc253dfb72461e7f4ef07dc815df0400 to 3f5931a
a55e9d9 (origin/feature/crud-suppliers, feature/crud-suppliers) HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from feature/crud-suppliers to a55e9d9
a55e9d9 (origin/feature/crud-suppliers, feature/crud-suppliers) HEAD@{12}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/feature/crud-suppliers
a55e9d9 (origin/feature/crud-suppliers, feature/crud-suppliers) HEAD@{13}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~2
a55e9d9 (origin/feature/crud-suppliers, feature/crud-suppliers) HEAD@{14}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/feature/crud-suppliers
a55e9d9 (origin/feature/crud-suppliers, feature/crud-suppliers) HEAD@{15}: rebase -i (pick): CRUD employees
3f5931a HEAD@{16}: rebase -i (pick): Added new ways to retreive company informations
8dd9857 HEAD@{17}: rebase -i (pick): Created company user views
faedafc HEAD@{18}: rebase -i (pick): Changed email link to reset password
9b54992 HEAD@{19}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~2
b69bfb0 HEAD@{20}: commit (amend): Merge pull request #11 from alebuffoli/feature/crud-employees
069daa3 (origin/develop, develop) HEAD@{21}: checkout: moving from feature/crud-products to feature/crud-suppliers
```

---

#### Update

The method suggested below worked, but as a matter of fact, before to receive any reply on this question I was able to recover all my lost changes with the history function on my editor (Pycharm), so I guess to mention it if you are in a similar situation and cannot recover the changes with the methods below.

Comment: After a rebase the HEAD reflog can be a bit of a mess, since it records each move of the HEAD ref and there are potentially many entries for the rebase.  You might have better luck with the branch reflog.  In any case, it looks like b69bfb0 is likely where your changes are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` also keeps a log for individual branches : run

```
git reflog feature/crud-suppliers
```

to view only actions that moved that branch.

---

By default : `git rebase` completely drops merge commits. If your changes were stored in commit `Merge pull request #11 from ...`, then running `git rebase HEAD~2` would discard that commit.

You can use [`-r|--rebase-merges`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--r) to keep them.

Comment: You have just saved me from giving up on my developer career. Thank you!